# How can I disable some objects in arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have a script for gun switching, it have an array to get the MeshRenderer component of all elements, then, i can enable the element that i want, but i cannot disable the others.

```
public class TrocarArma : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    public int choosenGun = 0;
    [Space(10)]
    [SerializeField] MeshRenderer[] meshes = new MeshRenderer[4];

    void Start()
    {
        SelectWeapon();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ChangeGun();
    }

    void SelectWeapon()
    {
        int gunCount = 0;                                                             

        meshes[0] = GameObject.Find("GravityGun").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        meshes[1] = GameObject.Find("IronBar").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        meshes[2] = GameObject.Find("Tablet").GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        meshes[3] = null;                                                      //Will be filled later.

        foreach(Transform gun in transform)
        {
            if (gunCount == choosenGun)
            {
                meshes[choosenGun].enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                 ///Code to make the others array meshes elements MeshRenderers disable.
            }

            gunCount++;
        }
    }

    void ChangeGun()
    {
        int previousWeapon = choosenGun;

        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0)
        {
            if(choosenGun >= transform.childCount -1)
            {
                choosenGun = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                choosenGun++;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0)
        {
            if (choosenGun <= 0)
            {
                chooseGun = transform.childCount - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                chooseGun--;
            }
        }

        if (previousWeapon != chooseGun)
        {
            SelectWeapon();
        }
    }
}
```

I simply not used **SetActive(true)/(false)** because I need my tablet active to upgrade my defenses. The video that i make this script: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dn_BUIVdAPg , thanks for reading!

Comment: have you tried `meshes[choosenGun].enabled = false;`?

Comment: Yeah, but it not worked, i will try a switch to disable the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have strange logic inside `void SelectWeapon()` method. But, I dare to suggest that the following code can help you:

```
foreach(Transform gun in transform)
{
    if (gunCount == choosenGun)
    {
        meshes[choosenGun].enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        meshes[gunCount].enabled = false;
    }

    gunCount++;
}
```

or

```
foreach(Transform gun in transform)
{           
    switch(gunCount)
    {
        case 0:
            meshes[choosenGun].enabled = true;
            break;

        default:
            meshes[gunCount].enabled = false;
            break;
    }

    gunCount++;
}
```

By the way:
`meshes[3] = null;` will throw an exception when you try to access the `.enabled` property. It is better not to allow such null elements, or always to check for null.

Comment: I will try this, I made a big switch, it worked, the guns that aren't selected now are properly disabled. 

https://pastebin.com/Pmt8T6TR

Comment: or simply `meshes[choosenGun].enabled = gunCount == choosenGun;` ;)

Comment: note that either way for `meshes[3] = null;` you will get a `NulReferenceException` when reaching that index ....

Comment: @derHugo Ok, i will do it!

Comment: I added a ghost transform with mesh renderer component, now I instantiate my defenses in that transform, with **GetComponentInChildren()** I disabled the defense, so, the console is full clean now, thank you for helping, and the tips for the null keyword! :D